Adverbs, before or after the verb?
First year student here, so this may be a trivial question:
Does an adverb come normally before or after the verb?
My textbook says that when making a statement, place it before the verb. For example: *я медленно говорю. *  Except that when answer a "как" question in which case place it after the verb: Я говорю медленно.
My wife says it doesn't make any difference, and in searches, I see it recommended both ways.  Is there any actual difference?  In my experience, I seem to have seen in come before the verb.  In English, it typically comes after the verb: "I speak slowly". If I used it before: "I slowly speak to him" it would emphasize that I speak slowly, but it seems to me you would only say this in response to a question. But "I speak to him slowly" would mean almost exactly the same.
Is it the same type of thing in Russian?

I will leave a proper answer to a native speaker with more knowledge, but your textbook isn't wrong. There is a "normal" place for an adverb (я плохо понимаю, for example), which is different to the normal place in English. And if the adverb is put somewhere else it has more emphasis. In addition to these considerations, word order is less fixed in Russian than in English anyway. I'd follow the textbook. Asking your wife is asking a non-expert, even if she is a native speaker.

Great, thank you.  If you post as an answer, I will accept.

Well, I think you will get a better answer. Hold on a couple of days.

Here's a good thread on this subject: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13147/order-of-adverbs-and-position-of-subject

And this one: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/order-of-adverbial-of-time-in-sentences.2911575/#post-14719451

You are absolutely right that the only thing that changes in these sentences is the accent. The order of words in Russian can be chosen freely, but the last word usually carries the accent. For example, "Я говорю медленно" answers the question, "How do I speak?", whereas "Я медленно говорю" answers the question, "What do I do slowly?" That's essentially what you wrote. However, you can also do the same with intonation when speaking. In the sentence "Я медленно говорю" you can say the word "медленно" a bit louder, emphasizing the word, then it does the same job. It's just that having the accent in the middle of the sentence is a bit more awkward, so less common, also doing it in writing is impossible.
P.S. In short, the order of words in writing plays the same role as accent while speaking, so should be chosen more carefully.


Is there any actual difference?

There is a difference in the information structure (topic and comment) of the sentence.

Is it the same type of thing in Russian?

In Russian, there are two things in play that define the information structure of the sentence: the order of words and the so-called "logical stress" (логическое ударение). They are closely related and affect each other.
The logical stress (in Russian, conveyed with higher loudness and the pitch lower or higher than normal) marks the comment of the sentence. Comment is the new information that the sentence is supposed to convey.
The most natural order of words in a sentence depends on the style of the speech.
In neutral or formal speech the comment (and, hence, the logically stressed word that defines it) tends to go to the end of the phrase. In your example, assuming that the comment (the new information) is the slowness of your speech, the most natural order in neutral speech would be я говорю медленно. Since медленно is a comment in that sentence, it goes to the end and you pronounce it a little louder and with a slightly lower pitch. Had the topic been говорю (meaning that it's talking that you do slowly, as opposed to other things you do lightning fast), you would need to use я медленно говорю.
In colloquial speech, the comment goes to the penultimate position (before the last word). In that case, the meaning gets reversed. Я мéдленно говорю would mean "I speak slowly (as opposed to fast)", and я говорю́ медленно would mean "I speak slowly (as opposed to doing dishes)". The order of the word changes, but the logical stress (loudness and pitch) still goes on the comment.
Finally, in Russian, as in many other languages with less strict word order, you can use the hyperbaton, which inverses the natural order of words in a sentence for rhetoric purposes. The order of the words in this case is defined more by the prosody of the speech than by anything else, but the logical stress still stays on the comment. This is heavily used in poetry (and especially the folk poetry).
As you can imagine, this all can be both a curse and a blessing for written texts, which don't convey the logical stress.
If your sentence has a pretty much obvious topic-comment structure, you can use the word order to give your text one style or the other. E.g. я сейчас пойду в магазин, тебе что-нибудь нужно? vs. я сейчас в магазин пойду, тебе что-нибудь нужно? have markedly distinct styles
If a sentence has two possible readings, then it's the other way around: you need to figure out the overall style of the text to figure out the intended order of the topic and the comment. This can be a challenge for a language learner.
